# create HBITMAP with alpha channel from BMP files

Tags: winapi, gdi

I started with a PNG image. I then split the alpha channel into a grey scale BMP file and converted the PNG into a BMP.
I would like to load both BMP files and merge them to give a HBITMAP with an alpha channel:

```
HBITMAP splash = LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_SPLASH));
HBITMAP splashMask = LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_SPLASH_MASK));
HBITMAP splashAlpha = ....
```

I found an [example](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/09/displaying_a_splash_screen_with_c_part_i.html) of creating a HBITMAP directly from a PNG. It uses IStream and COM to do the import. I'd rather not include more dependencies. Surely there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for minimum code, you should consider converting your PNGs into a 32-bit bitmap and draw them using the [AlphaBlend API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
BLENDFUNCTION fn;
ZeroMemory(&fn, sizeof(fn));
fn.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
fn.BlendFlags = 0;
fn.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
fn.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
AlphaBlend(dstDC, dstX, dstY, dstW, dstH, hdcSrc, srcX, srcY, srcW, srcH, fn);
```

The gotcha is that hdcSrc should refer to a 32-bit BGRA image where the Alpha channel is premultiplied into the BGR channels, i.e.

```
B = B * A / 255;
G = G * A / 255;
R = R * A / 255;
```